# How to use line_profiler without counting the running time in the first loop in python?

Tags: python

The [line_profiler](https://pypi.org/project/line-profiler/) is very handy to analyze code performance line by line. I have a python function that is called `N` times and I want to measure its time performance using `line_profiler`. The problem is, python takes extra time to compile the function during the first running loop. And in my case, I am not interested to take into consideration the compiling time when analyzing the performance. Is there a way to ignore the time overhead of compiling the code when profiling the code in python?